# Defining the scope of the "judgement" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Despite its frequent use, the [judgment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judgment) is currently without a tag-wiki description.  It is also a rather ambiguous term and has been used on several different kinds of questions, including:

- God's judgment of individuals or groups of people within Biblical history [(Example)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15076/sarah-laughed-at-god-and-he-did-not-mind)
- God's judgment of people after they die [(Example)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5604/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-multiple-judgments-after-death)
- The final judgment [(Example)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4470/according-to-catholic-doctrine-what-effect-does-the-last-judgment-have-on-those)
- Teachings on practice of judging of others (i.e "judge not, lest ye be judged", etc.). Ex: [(Example)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/can-christians-be-judges)
- Miscellaneous uses along the lines of how do we decided whether such and such is true

It seems to me that while there is some overlap, it would be wise to more narrowly define the tag and split this up.  How should this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for raising this issue! I've been wanting to address it. Your tag maintenance is appreciated. I have a different take on how it should shake out, however.

- If God's judgment within Biblical history warrants any tag, it would probably be [punishment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punishment).
- I agree that [final-judgment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-judgment) should be a synonym of eschatology, but any question about the fate of people after death should be able to fit in one or more of the [heaven](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heaven), [hell](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hell), [purgatory](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purgatory), [universalism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universalism), [afterlife](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afterlife), and [death](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) tags without needing a tag of its own.
- I agree that questions about judging other people should be given its own tag, and I think [judging-others](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judging-others) works just fine.
- Miscellaneous ones should be removed.

In short, [judgment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judgment) should be nuked, and the questions should be given other tags where appropriate.

Comment: I see we also have [tag:punishment]; that would probably be a good substitute for the first class, as most/of all these questions are asking why God exerted such-as-such punishment on people.  And we also have [tag:afterlife] (which arguably could be a synonym of death, or death of it, but that is another issue for another time); so I think I am persuaded that a judgment tag is not needed.  Would you mind editing your answer to add those two tags?

Comment: @ThaddeusB Thanks, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: -1 God's judgement is not always synonymous with punishment. Abraham was judged righteous, for example. Mary was judged righteous, too.

Comment: Maybe [gods-judgement] would be suitable for those cases?

Comment: @Flimzy Obviously I'm not saying cases like that should have the [tag:punishment] tag. But I really don't think such questions would have enough in common to warrant a common tag.

Answer (score 1):

- [judgment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judgment) should be defined something along the lines of "God's decision to reward or punish people, either while still living or after death."  This will capture the first two usages
- Questions about the final judgment should be tagged [eschatology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eschatology) and left in [judgement](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judgement) only if they are directly about the judgment aspect.   That is, if the question is along the lines of "when will this happen", then the judgment tag is removed, but if it is along the lines of "what will happen to people/satan/etc." then it is given both tags.  [final-judgment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-judgment) should be added as a synonym of [eschatology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eschatology) to aid users in finding the correct tag.
- Questions about humans judging humans should be tagged [judging-others](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judging-others) or something similar (no such tag exists yet, so I'm open to suggestions)
- Miscellaneous uses should be removed from [judgment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judgment), as likely has generally been done in the past